# The problem that jpa custom query does not take effect

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am designing a 'like' function for a blog system, and I want to judge whether the likes have been added/applied according to the user's login status when querying the content of the homepage.

So I have created a SQL statement to implement the left join to the query to achieve this function. I used the JPA @Query jpql method to customize the query, but the effect is different from what I expected.

When looking at the statement, I found that the jpql statement is indeed executed once, but it is an associated query to another/subsequent jpa query after the initial query was executed, so I think it may be overwritten.

I am using jpa for the first time and they may be thing that I do not fully understand, please feel free to ask any further questions to help me and thank you.

This is my expected sql statement：

```
SELECT a.*,l.*FROM article a LEFT JOIN user_like_record l ON a.id=l.target_id AND l.target_type=0 AND l.user_id=17
```

This is my current code：

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT\n" +
        "\tarticle\n" +
        "FROM\n" +
        "\tArticle article LEFT JOIN article.userLikeRecord ON article.userLikeRecord.targetType = 0\n" +
        "\t AND article.userLikeRecord.userId = :userId")
Page<Article> findAllLikeStatusb(Long userId, Pageable pageable);

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "target_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private UserLikeRecord userLikeRecord;
```

This is the sql statement generated by the last query of jpa:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    user0_.id as id1_9_,
    user0_.create_time as create_t2_9_,
    user0_.delete_time as delete_t3_9_,
    user0_.update_time as update_t4_9_,
    user0_.email as email5_9_,
    user0_.mobile as mobile6_9_,
    user0_.nick_name as nick_nam7_9_,
    user0_.openid as openid8_9_,
    user0_.receive_like_counts as receive_9_9_,
    user0_.unify_uid as unify_u10_9_,
    user0_.user_birthday as user_bi11_9_,
    user0_.wx_profile as wx_prof12_9_ 
from
    user user0_ 
where
    (
        user0_.delete_time is null
    ) 
    and user0_.openid=?
Hibernate: 
SELECT
    a.*,
    l.* 
FROM
    article a 
LEFT JOIN
    user_like_record l 
        ON a.id = l.target_id 
        AND l.target_type=0 
        AND l.user_id =? 
order by
    a.create_time desc limit ?
```

The following sql is executed multiple times

```
Hibernate: 
select
    userlikere0_.target_id as target_i1_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.create_time as create_t2_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.delete_time as delete_t3_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.update_time as update_t4_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.id as id5_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.like_status as like_sta6_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.target_type as target_t7_10_0_,
    userlikere0_.user_id as user_id8_10_0_ 
from
    user_like_record userlikere0_ 
where
    userlikere0_.target_id=? 
    and (
        userlikere0_.delete_time is null
    )
```

Comment: *`.. LEFT JOIN article.userLikeRecord ON ..`* Does `article` is database name and `userLikeRecord` is table name? If not then you try to join a column, not a table. *This is my expected sql statement* It differs from one ised in the code.

Comment: For the name of the table, because the jpql statement is written here, there will be article.userLikeRecord. I have also adjusted the native sql method, but the effect has not come out later. It may not be very intuitive to say here. I will paste the jpa query above for you to take a look. I have tested that the sql statement generated by jpa is normal, but it is strange that jpa has performed multiple where queries in the subsequent operations. Maybe because the onetoone relationship is overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN? Maybe, it's the case to use an INNER JOIN.

LEFT OUTER JOIN JQPL:

```sql
SELECT article
FROM Article article LEFT JOIN article.userLikeRecord lk
WHERE (lk.targetType IS NULL OR lk.targetType = 0)
AND (lk.userId IS NULL OR lk.userId = :userId)
```

INNER JOIN JPQL:

```sql
SELECT article
FROM Article article
JOIN article.userLikeRecord lk
WHERE lk.targetType = 0
AND lk.userId = :userId
```